# How to launch an application with default "terminal emulator" on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, terminal

I wanted to execute some command in terminal emulator, like Konsole, but I need to make this cross-desktop.

Is there some command like `xdg-open`, but for getting the default terminal emulator?

I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In **Debian**, you could just call `x-terminal-emulator -e /some/command`, as this points to the terminal emulator configured by Debian's "*alternative*" mechanism.   It's configured via

```
# update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

which lets you chose *which of the installed X11 terminal emulators* to use as the default one, i.e. as `x-terminal-emulator`.  In the end, it's a symlink construction, e.g. for `gnome-terminal`:

```
$ which x-terminal-emulator
/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
$ ls -al /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Apr 26  2010 /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator -> /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator
$ ls -al /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Apr 26  2010 /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator -> /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
$ file /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

Some remarks,

- [I'm not sure if Ubuntu works analogously, though.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72517/where-can-i-set-the-default-terminal-emulator)
- There seems to be (have been?) [something called `xdg-terminal`](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2006-December/007290.html), but [apparently not in Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=604959).

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work on Fedora 16 with Gnome 3.2.1

Comment: @AaronLewis Note that this is the system default. I don't think there's any standard way of obtaining the user's favorite X terminal emulator.