# Launching a terminal emulator without knowing which ones are installed

Tags: shell-script, terminal-emulator, portability

I need to write a script that will launch a terminal emulator and run a particular command in it. Since I don't know which terminal emulators have been installed on the target system, how could I find which terminal emulators have been installed?

I've looked at [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91642/what-is-the-most-portable-method-of-launching-a-terminal-emulator). However, I'm not really very inclined to make a hardcoded check, and I'm searching for a generic solution.

I've come up this *very* dirty hack, but I'm really not sure how this would fare:

`termdetect`:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=:
for i in $PATH; do
  find "$i" -type f -exec isterminal {} \;
done
```

`isterminal`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -z "$1" ]]; then
  if [[ "$(head -c 4 "$1")" == $'\x7fELF' ]]; then
    if ! grep editor "$1" > /dev/null; then
      if grep -E '(vte_terminal_|libutempter|rxvt_)' "$1" > /dev/null; then
        echo "$1"
      fi
    fi
  fi
fi
```

Is there an easy generic solution that I'm perhaps missing? Or do I have no other way than to scour binaries for hints or use a hardcoded list?

Comment: This looks like it would have plenty of false positives.

Comment: @Gilles, I'm aware of the possibility of false positives, that's why I asked for a better solution. Nevertheless, you (and other readers) are welcome to report on the effectiveness of the stated solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your heuristics are pretty bad. Here's what they find on a Debian wheezy machine of mine (I've manually marked correct hits with a `+`).

```
/usr/bin/gcm-calibrate
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal        +
/usr/bin/mosh-client   
/usr/bin/mosh-server
/usr/bin/mrxvt                 +
/usr/bin/mrxvt-full            +
/usr/bin/roxterm               +
/usr/bin/rxvt-unicode          +
/usr/bin/urxvt                 +
/usr/bin/urxvtd
/usr/bin/vinagre
/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator   +
/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal        +
/usr/bin/xterm                 +
```

If you pick the first alphabetic match, it's a color calibrator.

Here's the list of alternatives for `x-terminal-emulator`, which is the correct answer (as far as distribution-managed programs is concerned) on this Debian machine:

```
/usr/bin/Eterm
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
/usr/bin/koi8rxterm
/usr/bin/konsole
/usr/bin/lxterm
/usr/bin/mlterm
/usr/bin/mrxvt-full
/usr/bin/roxterm
/usr/bin/rxvt-xpm
/usr/bin/rxvt-xterm
/usr/bin/urxvt
/usr/bin/uxterm
/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper
/usr/bin/xterm
/usr/bin/xvt
```

You're finding 7 out of 15 (accounting for vagaries of names), which isn't a very good hit rate.

You could try to refine your heuristics, but it's a never-ending game. The minimum would be to retain only executables that both link against some X11 libraries and call some master terminal function or utility like `getpt` or `grantpt`, but that's bound to find a lot of spurious positives too, and to miss executables where the call is in a library (like `konsole`). And this will miss native code executables that are accessed through a shell wrapper (there are several in my list).

Detecting whether a program is an X terminal emulator from the executable content is hopeless.

Detecting programs by name is a far better heuristic.

Note also that different programs have a different command line syntax. Most of them accept `-T TITLE` and `-e COMMAND`, but they have different parsing rules for `-e` (going through a shell or not, taking multiple arguments or not) so you should pass a single parameter after `-e`, not containing any shell special characters.

On Debian and derivatives, [`x-terminal-emulator`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#s11.8.3) is guaranteed to be an X terminal emulator that supports `-T` and `-e`, such that `-e` uses all subsequent command line parameters as a command and its argument and doesn't do shell expansion on them. Because some emulators behave differently, `x-terminal-emulator` is sometimes a wrapper that takes a more xterm-like syntax (`gnome-terminal.wrapper` and `xfce4-terminal.wrapper` are two examples of this).

I don't know of anything like this on other unix variants. For anything like portability, a hard-coded list of program names is your best bet.

Furthermore, detecting installed terminal emulators won't give you any idea about the user's preferences. For example, if I use Gnome, I probably don't want your application to launch Konsole — unless I happen to prefer Konsole, but how would you know that?

The de facto standard for user preferences is via [FreeDesktop.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org) specifications. Freedesktop publishes an [`xdg-utils`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org) package which contains programs such as [`xdg-open`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html) to open a document in the proper application, [`xdg-email`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-email.html) to launch the user's preferred email composing application, and more to the point [`xdg-terminal`](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2006-October/007058.html) to open the user's preferred terminal emulator.

This would make `xdg-terminal` the right thing to use, and you should use it if it's there. Unfortunately, `xdg-terminal` isn't available everywhere; for example, Debian doesn't ship it (it's a [long-idle bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=604959)). Furthermore [`xdg-terminal`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/tree/scripts/xdg-terminal.in) allows a single command argument, and is not consistent about what kind of expansion this argument undergoes.

Whatever you do, make sure to provide an easy way for the caller to specify a preference. Even `xdg-terminal` doesn't always get it right.

Thus your best strategy is:

1. if the user has specified a preference, use it
2. else try `xdg-terminal`
3. else try `x-terminal-emulator`
4. else try a hard-coded list

Answer (score 2):

On Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint, …), `x-terminal-emulator` will always launch the administrator's default graphical terminal.
You can even include something like this to determine if it's a graphical session:

```
if [ -z "$XAUTHORITY" ]
then 
 echo "Failed to launch terminal emulator! This is not a graphical session."
else
 x-terminal-emulator
fi
```

Comment: `x-terminal-emulator` is absent on a large number of distros, like CentOS and Arch Linux.

Comment: As I know, this is the only way to go. Have you seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32547/how-to-launch-an-application-with-default-terminal-emulator-on-ubuntu) question on the topic?
Maybe including an `if` statement to determine the distribution and only go for your dirty hack if this method doesn't work on that distribution.