# Launch default terminal emulator by command

Tags: terminal, xdg

How do I launch the default terminal emulator by command? `x-terminal-emulator` won't work because I'm not using a Debian and `xdg-terminal` doesn't seem to exist either. Is there any other way to launch the default terminal emulator?

It will be on GNOME although the terminal might not be `gnome-terminal` but e.g. `tilix` instead.

Already found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137782/launching-a-terminal-emulator-without-knowing-which-ones-are-installed), but a hard-coded list or something similar probably won't do, because I'm looking for a single command that can perform this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *generic* concept of default terminal emulator.

To get the GNOME desktop's default, use the following commands (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647630/4457671):

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg
```

Answer (score 1):

As [egmont already described](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481403/97255), there are no defaults for the terminal emulators, as the implementations vary greatly.

I have replied in longer format to a similar question on Super User, [Find the default terminal emulator](https://superuser.com/q/1153988/399707) with this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1461079/1011350).

Comment: Some desktops do have a setting for default terminal though.  In XFCE `exo-open  --launch TerminalEmulator` should launch the terminal set in `xfce-settings`.  Cinnamon also has a setting for default terminal.  No idea where these are stored though.