# Wayland: Execute command in default terminal

Tags: bash, shell-script, x11, wayland

In the past, I've been using `x-terminal-emulator -e "$COMMAND"` to launch commands in a new instance of the default terminal emulator while trying to be as compatible and DE independent as possible.
Obviously though, x-terminal-emulator doesn't exist on Wayland. What's the best alternative for a way for detecting the preferred terminal emulator that works on Wayland?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launch default terminal emulator by command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481142/launch-default-terminal-emulator-by-command) Speaking of `x-terminal-emulator` - it's not what you think it is, it's not a command which runs a generic default emulator, it's Gnome specific.

Comment: It kind of does, albeit not being the answer I was hoping for. Thank you!