What keycodes can be used for keyboard shortcuts in Nemo file manager?
In the Nemo file manager (the default in Linux Mint), what keycodes can be used to specify non-alphabetic keyboard keys?  Specifically, I want to assign Ctrl+; to a built-in Nemo function.  I have no difficulty assigning the function to a key combination like Ctrl+e (by modifying the accels/nemo file), but I want to assign it to Ctrl+;.
What I've tried:

<Primary>;
<Primary>\;
<Primary>semicolon
<Primary>Semicolon
<Primary>SEMICOLON
<Primary>KEY_Semicolon
<Primary>KEY_SEMICOLON
<Primary>KC_Semicolon
<Primary>KC_SEMICOLON
<Primary>KP_Semicolon
<Primary>KP_SEMICOLON

The only one that seems to come close is:

<Primary>semicolon

Using that keycode will list the desired keyboard shortcut in Nemo's UI, but it does not work.  Nemo seems to reject any of the other keycodes above, and does not even display them in its UI.


Add export GNOME22_USER_DIR="$HOME/.config/nemo" to ~/.profile.
Create an empty file ~/.config/nemo/accels/nemo.
Restart the System, start Nemo, close Nemo.
The file created in 2. now should have been filled with all available actions. If not, see below list.
Edit the desired lines, remove the comment character (;) and spaces from the start. Save your changes in a backup. Nemo sometimes seems to overwrite that file partially.
Restart the system.

For reference, this is what Nemo currently writes into that file (As you see, it also lists user scripts):
; nemo GtkAccelMap rc-file         -*- scheme -*-
; this file is an automated accelerator map dump
;
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/New Window" "<Primary>n")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Sidebar List" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/File" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Sort by Size" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenAlternate" "<Primary><Shift>o")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/RenameSelectAll" "<Shift>F2")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Hide Menubar" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Zoom In" "<Primary>plus")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Cut" "<Primary>x")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Go to Computer" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Create Link" "<Primary>m")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Redo" "<Primary>y")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/CompactView" "<Primary>3")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Add Bookmark" "<Primary>d")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Preferences" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ClipboardActions/Copy" "<Primary>c")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ScriptsGroup/script_file:\\s\\s\\shome\\snils\\s.local\\sshare\\snemo\\sscripts\\smake_folder_starter.py" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Reversed Order" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/TabsPrevious" "<Primary>Page_Up")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenAccel" "<Alt>Down")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Delete" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/No Templates" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationDelete" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Stop" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/New Documents" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationCopy" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Go" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Close" "<Primary>w")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Connect To Server Link" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Eject Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Stop Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationRestoreFromTrash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab9" "<Alt>0")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Unmount Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenAsRoot" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Sort by Name" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Keep Aligned" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Poll" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Edit" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Zoom Out" "<Primary>minus")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab8" "<Alt>9")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Go to Network" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Thumbnails" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInNewTab" "<Primary><Shift>t")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OtherApplication2" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Move to next pane" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/NemoShortcuts" "<Primary>F1")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Back" "<Alt>Left")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Bookmarks" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Select Pattern" "<Primary>s")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Open With" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab7" "<Alt>8")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/BrowseMoveTo" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OtherApplication1" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/TabsMoveLeft" "<Primary><Shift>Page_Up")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Start Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab6" "<Alt>7")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Properties" "<Alt>Return")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Home" "<Alt>Home")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Go to Trash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Poll" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Stop Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Hide Sidebar" "F9")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Mount Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Copy to Home" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab5" "<Alt>6")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Move to Desktop" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Reset to Defaults" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationOpenInNewTab" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Sort by Detailed Type" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab4" "<Alt>5")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInTerminal" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/CopyToMenu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Forward" "<Alt>Right")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab3" "<Alt>4")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/About Nemo" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Clean Up" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Open" "<Primary>o")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/TabsMoveRight" "<Primary><Shift>Page_Down")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/IconView" "<Primary>1")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/View" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Sort by Modification Date" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Select All" "<Primary>a")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab2" "<Alt>3")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationTrash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Unmount Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationPasteFilesInto" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab0" "<Alt>1")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Eject Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenContainingFolder" "<Primary><Alt>o")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab1" "<Alt>2")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Pin File" "<Primary><Shift>d")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Duplicate" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Edit Location" "<Primary>l")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationProperties" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Help" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Close All Windows" "<Primary>q")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Hide Toolbar" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Copy to Desktop" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Self Eject Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Rename" "F2")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/SplitViewNextPane" "F6")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Unfavorite File" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Empty Trash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Hide Statusbar" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Connect to Server" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Go to Templates" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/New Tab" "<Primary>t")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/NemoHelp" "F1")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/FollowSymbolicLink" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/ZoomOutAccel" "<Primary>KP_Subtract")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/ZoomInAccel2" "<Primary>KP_Add")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Manual Layout" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Edit Bookmarks" "<Primary>b")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/New Empty Document" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/NemoPluginManager" "<Alt>p")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Start Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Unpin File" "<Primary><Shift>d")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Self Start Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Undo" "<Primary>z")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/TabsNext" "<Primary>Page_Down")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Arrange Items" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Sort by Trash Time" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ClipboardActions/Select All" "<Primary>a")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Self Poll" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/New Folder" "<Primary><Shift>n")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Mount Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Reload" "<Primary>r")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Restore From Trash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/MoveToMenu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Favorite File" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "<Alt>Up")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenCloseParent" "<Shift><Alt>Down")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Paste Files Into" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Copy to next pane" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Zoom Normal" "<Primary>0")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Search" "<Primary>f")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Self Unmount Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Move to Home" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Self Mount Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/PropertiesAccel" "<Primary>i")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Self Stop Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Paste" "<Primary>v")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ClipboardActions/Paste" "<Primary>v")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationOpenAlternate" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/ListView" "<Primary>2")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/BrowseCopyTo" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Sidebar Places" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Hidden Files" "<Primary>h")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/LocationCut" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ClipboardActions/Cut" "<Primary>x")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/SplitViewSameLocation" "<Alt>s")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Copy" "<Primary>c")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Sidebar Tree" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Trash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/ZoomInAccel" "<Primary>equal")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/IconViewActions/Sort by Type" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Invert Selection" "<Primary><Shift>i")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Show Hide Extra Pane" "F3")


References: 1, 2, 3, 4,
5

Thank you, but that's an explanation of how to add/modify keyboard shortcuts in Nemo.  I'm looking for the keycodes that can be used in that file.

@EndAnti-SemiticHate what about this? https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=264754

Same thing. That doesn't contain a list of the keycodes that can be used in the aforementioned file.

@EndAnti-SemiticHate what about this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434231/customed-keyboard-shortcut ?

Same thing. No list of keycodes Nemo accepts.
